# When data is stored on one object but can only be manipulated by another what's the correct way to model it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is a slightly esoteric question but it's one that's puzzled me for a while. The question is how you correctly assign rights to manipulating a particular piece of data and whether it's possible to do this as party of the Ruby language.

Let's say we've got a Teacher, Pupil and an Answer

(**NB** I've just made the code up to create an illustration so it's probably syntactically flawed and it's not the best example in the world but it illustrates the point)

```
class Teacher < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :marked_answers, :class => :answer

  def mark_homework homework, correct_answers
    homework.answers.each do |answer|
     if answer == correct_answers.shift
       answer.mark_as_correct
     else
       answer.mark_as_incorrect
    end
  end
end

class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :teacher
  belongs_to :pupil

  def mark_as_correct
    self.correct = true
  end

  def mark_as incorrect
    self.correct = false
  end
end

class Pupil < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :answers

end
```

The question is, how do you ensure that only the teacher can mark the answer? What's to stop the pupil from marking the answer as correct too (aside from not giving them that piece of code)?

Is there a way to enforce in the answer that answer.mark_as_correct can only be called by a Teacher object?

I realise that you would normally solve this in the controller rather than the model but I'm interested in whether it can be done in the model.

Answer (score 0):

I handle these situations on the Controller level, using [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) gem.

For this case, you'd be looking at something like this in your Ability model, assuming teachers can be identified by `current_user.teacher?`:

```
can :mark, Answer if current_user.teacher?
```

Then in your controller, add this

```
raise "Some exception" if cannot? :mark, @answer
```

Comment: Thank you and I do realise that one can do this - I was wondering whether you could push the permissions deeper into the code?